# C++ Highlighting Bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

**EDIT** (to downvoters): downvoting implies that you think "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*". If this is the case, I would be glad to know which part you could possibly justify regarding this post, please post your answer in comment. Thanks.

---

Here is a minimal example of the problem I am experiencing:

```
#ifndef __ST2_HIGHLIGHT_TEST__
#define __ST2_HIGHLIGHT_TEST__

// This define makes the highlighting fail
#define create_obj( name, val ) obj<decltype(val)> name(val)

template <typename T>
struct obj
{
    obj( const T& val ): var(val) {}
    T var;
};

#endif
```

The comment above the define macro explains the problem: if I comment the macro, the highlighting is fine, otherwise it seems to cause the structure definition to be incorrectly highlighted (see pictures below).

I suspect a bug in the C++ rules used to highlight the code, and in this case, I think disabling the coloration of `define` macros altogether (in order to prevent them from messing with the coloration of the code that follows) would be a good solution. I don't know where to find these rules and how to update them to discard define statements though.

*Normal highlighting:*

[image]

*Suspected bug:*

[image]

*Note: I am using the following packages: BracketHighlighter, SublimeLinter, DocBlockr, SublimeCodeIntel*

Comment: How is the code being highlighted (highlit?)

Comment: Is it me or is this a meaning less question that's been upvoted twice?

Comment: I'm sorry, I see closing requests, is this not a proper programming question? I can paste the code of the highlighter and ask where to modify it if you want?

Comment: @RobKennedy See updated post, please let me know if I left something unclear.

Comment: Much better. Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me like the highlighter gets confused with what the context is when you have templates in macros. In this particular instance, you could possibly fix it by moving things around, but in general, the fix needs to be that the parser for the highlighter is "made smarter".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thank you for your comment, I would suspect a bug in the parser indeed; if the parser is derived from a grammar file, there might be an easy way to update the rules/replace the file in order to fix this bug?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the parser for Sublime, but yes, it's possible that you can update the some support file that defines what formatting to do when/where.

Comment: maybe you could make the macro a static inline function

Comment: @paulm The whole point of using a macro is that I am certain that the compiler will expand my code at compile-time, and therefore that I will not have to copy my object to return it. Also, I am unsure how to deal with the `name` argument of my macro in the case of a static inline function; could you please post an example code of your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Highlighting C++ code is really difficult in general. Basically, the highlighter must be almost as smart as a compiler. I assume ST is using regexps or similar, which is not always correct. I have seen it fail many times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As stated in my updated post, I think disabling the highlighting of define macros altogether would solve the problem, and I personally don't really care about the coloration of macros in general. Would you know how to do that by any chance?